# How to use entity with DBAL sqlsrv for easybundle admin

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, symfony4, dbal

Hello I have 2 databases connexion in my symfony and I want use an Entity and repository for simplify and finality use a EasyBundleAdmin, thanks advance

DBAL config :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
    default_connection:       web

    connections:
       web:
          driver: sqlsrv
          dbname:           WEBSITE_DBF
          user:             '%env(resolve:DB_USER)%'
          password:         '%env(resolve:DB_PASSWORD)%'
          host:             '%env(resolve:DB_HOSTNAME)%'
          charset: UTF-8
       account:
          driver: sqlsrv
          dbname:           ACCOUNT_DBF
          user:             '%env(resolve:DB_USER)%'
          password:         '%env(resolve:DB_PASSWORD)%'
          host:             '%env(resolve:DB_HOSTNAME)%'
          charset: UTF-8
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

Entity account:

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AccountRepository")
 */
class Account
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $account;

    private $result;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $connection = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('account');
        $result = $connection->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_TBL');
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    public function getAccount(): ?string
    {
        return $this->account;
    }
}
```

EasyAdmin config:

```
easy_admin:
   entities:
       - App\Entity\Account
```

error obtain is

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT a0_.account AS account_0, a0_.account AS account_1 FROM account a0_ ORDER BY a0_.account DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY':
```

because it's connect at default (website and not accounct connection) and my table is account_tbl and not account

I would like create entity for different connection for use asy admin bundle with DBAL thanks

Comment: Hi, you haven't really asked a question or described a problem here: what happens with the configuration you have, and what did you hope would happen instead?

Comment: I would like use easy admin with dbalanf for it, require anentity but I don't know how to work entity with DBAL because i'ts my first time with DBAL

Comment: You seem to have plenty of code already; what does it do? What does it not do that you want it to do? Remember that this isn't a code writing service, we need to understand what *specific* problem or query you have so that we can give you an answer.

Comment: Problem Is at work of entity because isnt working and easy admin dont work without entity

Comment: OK, so what does "isn't working" mean? Do you have some code that gives an error?

Comment: error is An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT DISTINCT a0_.account AS account_0, a0_.account AS account_1 FROM account a0_ ORDER BY a0_.account DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY':
and my base is an account_dbf and not website_dbf by default and my table is account_tbl and not "account" requete expected is : select account from account_dbf ... and not select account from account and connection account and not website connexion, sorry if isn't clear

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. Please can you [edit] all that detail into the question. Ideally, anyone reading the question should be able to both understand and recreate the actual problem you're having.

Comment: I have editing post